# How to define in Interface object array and work with it?

Tags: typescript

I have an object array by this example:

```
 tasks: todo =  [
      {
        title: string,
        status: number,
        description: string,
        date: Date,
        priority: number
      }
 ]
```

So I create an Interface for this:

```
interface todo {
  [index: number]:{
    title: string;
    status: number;
    description: string;
    date: Date;
    priority: number;
  }
}
```

and when I give to a variable, which has object array this interface, I've got errors:
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'todo'
and
Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'todo'.
How to prevent these errors?

**EDIT :
Found the solution:**

```
export interface todo extends Array <{
  title: string;
  status: number;
  description: string;
  date: Date;
  priority: number;
}> {}
```

Also the answer here is good too:

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  status: number;
  description: string;
  date: Date;
  priority: number;
}

// tasks is an array of Todo
tasks: Todo[] = [...];
```

Comment: Does it have to be an interface? Cannot you just type alias an array? `type todo = { ... }[];`?

Comment: Actually, early I described it as Object[], but my friend told me that the better way is to describe it with interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface should describe a single task/todo:

```
interface Todo {
  title: string;
  status: number;
  description: string;
  date: Date;
  priority: number;
}

// tasks is an array of Todo
tasks: Todo[] = [...];
```